# Is the Ginjo shown in chapter 681 of Bleach a 100% Shinigami?

Tags: bleach

By the end of the Substitute Shinigami Arc (Fullbring Arc), Ginjo was said to be dead, since Ichigo came to the captains' meeting and asked for Ginjo's body. Yet in chapter 681, Ginjo came with Tsukishima to help Ichigo. Does this means that the Ginjo in chapter 681 has turned into a 100% Shinigami, that is, he no longer is a Substitute Shinigami like he once was, but a 100% Shinigami since he is already dead and is a soul now?

(I guess 100% Shinigami is not a very good term to describe Ginjo since he was also a Fullbringer...)

Comment: Somehow I doubt this.   I doubt that he had died in the first place (as in, was actually confirmed dead in canon), and I doubt that he had a promotion to full Shinigami.  Further, if it were the case that he had died, him retaining his memories and abilities would moderately conflict with already established canon.  I may do a bit more research into this to figure it out, though.

Comment: The kid Chad saved remembers him when they met in Soul Society. Soul retain their memory in Bleach.

Answer (score 1):

Ginjo was the first fullbringer in the series, his fullbringer is the ability to steal or take, he killed many shinigami and took their powers, a substitute shinigami doesnt need to be a actual shinigami, ginjo acted as a subtitute shinigami for SS but he himself did not have a shikai nor bankai as he was not a shinigami but a fullbringer, he obtain shikai/bankai when he took ichigos powers.

Comment: that is why ginjo died rather easily to ichigo, same for tsukishima, those injuries on a shinigami or hollow are not much but for a human body is death, the only problem i find is how ginjo kept his youth even tho he is older than 40 by the looks of his past, like quincy fullbringers also have the ability to live long lifes it seems

Answer (score 0):

The [Wikia](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/K%C5%ABgo_Ginj%C5%8D) states that he gained his powers by stealing them from other soul reapers (according to  Suì-Fēng). He had to steal Ichigo's powers to get himself a Bankai. Simply going to Soul Society wouldn't mean that he would gain soul reaper status, since unlike Ichigo, it is not indicated that he had innate soul reaper family history and has not been given soul reaper powers after Ichigo got his back from him. However, the [Wikia](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Shinigami) also states that

> When souls with exceptional spiritual energy train their bodies, they reach the level of Shinigami.

so since Ginjo is already trained and has exceptional spiritual energy, technically he should be a soul reaper as a soul. So, humans need to have soul reaper family history or someone to give them their powers to become soul reapers, but souls are innately able to become soul reapers with training and strong spiritual energy.

Comment: how did he get the original powers than in order to become a substitute shinigami? no way a ordinary human could beat a shinigami, they cant even see them. I also HIGHLY doubt he needed ichigos power to obtain his bankai.

Comment: He got his powers from an unknown source. He then proceded to use his powers to kill shinigami and steal their powers, adding to his power. He lost his power eventually leaving only his fullbring, likely because he was exiled from seiretei. The plan of the fullbringers was to steal Ichigo's power to add to their own, but Ginjo took all of it for himself, thus getting a bankai with getsuga tenshou. Of course, as we all know now, it wasn't really a bankai that he took...

Comment: Rather than citing a fan-edited wiki, you should cite the source that the wiki itself cites.